# Error al parsear un texto como fecha en Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Estoy tratando de detectar el tipo de dato sugerido para un texto dado, con valores numéricos y/o texto no hay ningún problema, pero al trabajar con fechas la cosa se complica un poco por lo que existen muchas formas de expresar una fecha.

Por ejemplo si quiero validar el texto *"otoño 2019"*

```
Date.parse("otoño 2019")
```

Obtengo como resultado un valor

```
1546311600000
```

Al no obtener un error o un valor indefinido, no podría decir que no es una fecha, y es que de hecho, el valor obtenido viene siendo el mismo que se obtiene si en lugar de ese texto hubiese ejecutado

```
Date.parse("2019")
```

Estuve realizando pruebas con la librería de `moment.js`, pero obtengo un comportamiento relativamente similar.

¿Que me sugieren para poder detectar el tipo de dato de fechas de una forma más acertada?.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Cual seria el formato de fecha que necesitas verificar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta es la [respuesta traducida del foro en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript):

---

El mejor formato de cadena para el análisis de cadenas es el formato ISO de fecha junto con el constructor del objeto Fecha de JavaScript.

Ejemplos de formato ISO: `AAAA-MM-DD` o`AAAA-MM-DDTHH: MM: SS`.

**¡Pero espera!** Solo usar el "formato ISO" no funciona de manera confiable por sí solo. Las cadenas a veces se analizan como UTC y a veces como localtime (según el proveedor y la versión del navegador). La mejor práctica siempre debe ser almacenar fechas como UTC y realizar cálculos como UTC.

Para analizar una fecha como UTC, agregue una **Z**, por ejemplo: `new Date('2011-04-11T10: 20: 30Z')`.

Para mostrar una fecha en UTC, use `.toUTCString ()`, 
para mostrar una fecha en la hora local del usuario, use `.toString ()`.

Más información sobre [MDN | Fecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) y [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40768745/584192).

Para la compatibilidad con Internet Explorer anterior (las versiones de IE anteriores a la 9 no admiten el formato ISO en el constructor de fecha), debe dividir la representación de cadena de fecha y hora en sus partes y luego puede usar el constructor usando partes de fecha y hora, por ejemplo: `new Date('2011' '04' - 1, '11', '11', '51', '00')`. Tenga en cuenta que el número del mes debe ser 1 menos.

---

**Método alternativo: utilice una biblioteca adecuada:**

También puede aprovechar la biblioteca [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) que permite analizar la fecha con la zona horaria especificada.

---

Debes tener en cuenta que los sistemas solo pueden hacer conversiones a fechas "reales", ya que si intentas usar lenguaje natural, deberás crear tus propias sentencias para poder hacer entendible cosas como ***Otoño 2019*** para que el sistema lo pueda convertir a por ejemplo ***2019-10-01*** (Primero de octubre del 2019) o cosas similares

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta que hay muchas formas de expresar una fecha, es recomendable utlizar un formato de fecha. Por ejemplo que las fechas sigan el formato **dd/mm/yyyy** de esta forma limitas al usuario a que se apege al formato establecido. Para establecer un formato de fecha puedes utilizar un regex para validar que la fecha tecleada por el usuario cumple con el formato establecido.

A continuación te dejo un regex para validar fechas en formato dd/mm/yyyy

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

En [regex101](https://regex101.com/) puedes validar la expresión regular.

Ejemplo de implementación con HTML y JavaScript [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/quethzel/5d28afhw/23/)

Comment: Pudes salvar la regex en regex101 https://regex101.com/r/G2hs6I/1/ como en jsfiddle.